# Why does javac generate $n.class files?

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I've noticed that when compiling using `javac` it not only creates .class but also creates $1.class , $2.class... I don't seem to understand the purpose of creation of $n.class when they can all be compiled into one .class file. Is there any purpose for this behavior? Or is my interpretation of how `javac` works entirely wrong?

Comment: the $1 classes are inner classes

Comment: Your original question was closed as a duplicate. If you want to ask another, different question, then do that: ask another question. Editing an already closed question won't allow anyone to answer. Note that you should post the output of javap and the reasoning that made you think $1 is the second runnable.

Comment: @Paul They are *anonymous* inner classes.